# character 0xc286 of encoding "UTF-8" has no equivalent in "WIN1252"....On conversion with iconv postgres restore crashes

Tags: delphi, postgresql, character-encoding

I'm working on a software that uses delphi and postgres 9.0,
the original developer had chosen the database encoding as '**SQL_ASCII**'...
so we changed the encoding to **UTF-8** for our database..
we we started getting this error after

[image]
Onclick of the One of the check boxes
(the form is populated from the database)
the query where the error comes is

> 'select * from diary where survey in ('2005407')';

but this error only comes for few of the check boxes and not ALL

The change is straight forward but we have large amount of historical data that we will have to re-store into the newly created **UTF-8** database..so i followed the steps i found on the net and stackoverflow also

1. Dump the database as e- **UTF-8**   `SQL_Ascii_backup.backup`
2. Use iconv to convert **SQL_ASCII** to **UTF-8**

   ```
   "C:\Program Files\GnuWin32\bin\iconv.exe" -f ISO8859-1 -t UTF-8 C:\SQL_Ascii_backup.backup>UTF_Backup.backup
   ```

   3.Create a new Database with encoding as UTF-8 and re-store the backup `UTF_Backup.backup`

But when i try to restore it i get t his error
[image: Error when i try to restore the newly encoded backup]

then i tried with dumping the original **SQL_ASCII** database as plain `SQL_Ascii_.sql` file
and then again i used iconv to change the encoding..and then restoring

```
  >"C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.0\bin\psql.exe"-h localhost -p 5434 -d myDB -U myDB_admin -f C:\converted_utf8.sql
```

this is restoring properly but im still geting the error.

> 'character 0xc286 of encoding "UTF-8" has no equivalent in "WIN1252";

Comment: Where did the WIN1252 come from? Somewhere you got hit by one of uncle Bill's default settings. How is client_encoding set in pgadmin3? How is it specified in the dump file, when the DB is created?

Comment: After rereding the OP: the data got transformed Ok, but "the application" has some strange assumptions on the character encoding. Maybe there is a possibility to set client_encoding in the app ? Otherwise: nuke it. Or: recode the database tables to WIN1252. Or edit the few affected rows.

Comment: @wildplasser ..im not sure about the client_encoding in the application..i cannot go with the recoding with WIN1252 for the database, as the clients wants the database to be UTF-8....But how do i edit the affected row?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

C2 86 is the UTF-8 encoding of the character U+0086, an obscure [C1 control character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0_and_C1_control_codes#C1_set).  This character exists in [ISO-8859-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO-8859-1), but not in Windows' default [code page 1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252), which has printable characters in the space where ISO-8859-1 has the C1 controls.

Your iconv command to convert to UTF-8 has `-f ISO8859-1`, but your probably meant `-f windows-1252` instead.  This maps the byte 86 to the `†` character.

Comment: @dan04..i tried -f windows-1252 in the following command..""C:\Program Files\GnuWin32\bin\iconv.exe" -f windows-1252 -t UTF-8  C:\Mybackup.backup>convert.backup"...but then i get this error__ "iconv : C:\Mybackup.backup : cannot convert.

Comment: then i tried with plain .sql dump also with '"C:\Program Files\GnuWin32\bin\iconv.exe" -f windows-1252 -t UTF-8  C:\myBackup.sql>converted.sql' but still the same 'cannot convert' error

Comment: i found out that iconv was failing to convert the file as a result of this TRÂL..the square shaped character...i compared the myBackup.sql(3.19 Mb size) file and converted.sql (219 KB size) in beyond compare..so then i manually removed the character and ran the application..and it worked..there was no error

Comment: ok stackOverflow is not displaying the character ,its like this '[]' but a full square

Comment: how can i replace the '[]' character?..manually not an option ...the replace function also doesnt work

Answer (score 1):

I got rid of the error

> 'character 0xc286 of encoding "UTF-8" has no equivalent in "WIN1252";

by following **dan04** answer, but to prevent the iconv failing to convert the dumped

1. Dump the database **UTF-8** (do a plain dump..so you may be able to find the point of failure)
2. Use iconv to convert **SQL_ASCII** to **UTF-8** using

   > "C:\Program Files\GnuWin32\bin\iconv.exe" -f windows-1252 -t UTF-8    C:\MqPlainDump.sql>convertedDump.sql
3. Replace the '[]' character (this is in my case which was causing the trouble..its a square character)
4. Restore the database

And the application is good to go (in my case)