# Obtaining key codes for Alt+Numeric Keypad for use in SendKeys

Tags: delphi, keycode, ord

(I'm trying to make SendKeys code from the internet work with extended characters.) Sendkeys is an imitation of VB SendKeys. There are several algorithms that I've seen on the internet, plus the one that came with Delphi 7. My program uses it to send keystrokes to other programs to make data entry faster and more consistent. It works well except characters that Ord() reports with a number over 255.

Since posting this question I discovered that Character Map reports Alt+0128 through Alt+255. And it turns out that only 26 such characters are reported by Ord() with what appears to be a unicode value. So I now have an ugly work around that just replaces the values reported by Ord() with the alternate, lower, values reported by Character Map. So my Sendkeys now appears compatible with Ansi coding in Notepad.

I was hoping for a simple character conversion like AnsiChar() but that yielded completely wrong Ord() values.

I am using Delphi XE2 and Arial font for all of this question. 
The Windows Character Map utility reports that Alt + 0147 creates the "Left Double Quotation Mark".

This key combination delivers the “ character in a Delphi control, Notepad and Word.

All of my internet research says to use Ord() to determine the numeric value of a character:

```
Procedure ShowNumericKeypadCode(ch: Char);
begin
  showmessage('Key code = ' + Format('%4.4d',[Ord(ch)]));
end;
```

But this returns 8220, not 0178. Alt+8220 yields ∟ in Notepad and Delphi controls, but it still produces “ in Word.

This is apparently something to do with Ansi versus Unicode, but I can't figure out how to write a function in Delphi that will return the 0178 instead of 8220.

iConv will not be helpful since the goal is to have a stand alone program. Thanks.

Comment: We don't know what `SendKeys` is. However, faking more complex keyboard input is tricky. Often depends on keyboard layout. Perhaps if you would solve you problem without hacky input faking you'd have more joy.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use the (external) program `iconv`, which is mentioned in *[character 0xc286 of encoding “UTF-8” has no equivalent in “WIN1252”…On conversion with iconv postgres restore crashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8489881/character-0xc286-of-encoding-utf-8-has-no-equivalent-in-win1252-on-conver)*.  That refers to a program which can be downloaded from the [GNU Win32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/) website.

Given an implementation of `iconv`, one can convert UTF-8 to ASCII like this:

```
iconv -f UTF8 -t US-ASCII//TRANSLIT -o outputfile inputfile
```

For further discussion, these may help (there are some comments about using the `iconv.dll` directly):

- [Steps to enable and use iconv on Windows with Indy 10.5.9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14140315/steps-to-enable-and-use-iconv-on-windows-with-indy-10-5-9)
- [Re: iconv for delphi? or other way to detect a string's encoding and convert between encodings](http://coding.derkeiler.com/Archive/Delphi/alt.comp.lang.borland-delphi/2010-06/msg00007.html)
- [Indy 10, BCB6 and UTF-8](http://www.progtown.com/topic1319186-indy-10-bcb6-and-utf8.html)

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the Character Map utility reports key codes from Alt+0128 to Alt+0255 for upper ASCII characters that you can input via the numeric keypad. It also reports many more unicode characters with a hex value. If you convert that value to decimal, it too can be input via Alt+numeric keypad. I never discovered why Ord() reports a unicode value of 8220 but the hex is 201C and Character Map shows that as the same character as 0178. I found that out of the range from 0128 to 0255, there are only 26 characters that Ord() reports with a unicode value instead of the high ASCII values. That allows for an ugly work around:

```html
 numStr := Format('%4.4d',[Ord(ch)]);
      numStr :=  AnsiReplaceStr (numStr,'8216','0145');  //Convert from Unicode to Ansi to work with Notepad AND Word
      numStr :=  AnsiReplaceStr (numStr,'8217','0146');  
      numStr :=  AnsiReplaceStr (numStr,'8220','0147');  
      numStr :=  AnsiReplaceStr (numStr,'8221','0148');  
      numStr :=  AnsiReplaceStr (numStr,'0381','0141');  
      numStr :=  AnsiReplaceStr (numStr,'8226','0149');  
      numStr :=  AnsiReplaceStr (numStr,'8211','0150');  
      numStr :=  AnsiReplaceStr (numStr,'8364','0128');  
      numStr :=  AnsiReplaceStr (numStr,'8218','0130');  
      numStr :=  AnsiReplaceStr (numStr,'0402','0131');  
      numStr :=  AnsiReplaceStr (numStr,'8222','0132');  
      numStr :=  AnsiReplaceStr (numStr,'8230','0133');  
      numStr :=  AnsiReplaceStr (numStr,'8224','0134');  
      numStr :=  AnsiReplaceStr (numStr,'8225','0135');  
      numStr :=  AnsiReplaceStr (numStr,'0710','0136');  
      numStr :=  AnsiReplaceStr (numStr,'8240','0137');  
      numStr :=  AnsiReplaceStr (numStr,'0352','0138');  
      numStr :=  AnsiReplaceStr (numStr,'8249','0139');  
      numStr :=  AnsiReplaceStr (numStr,'0338','0140');  

      numStr :=  AnsiReplaceStr (numStr,'8212','0151');  
      numStr :=  AnsiReplaceStr (numStr,'0732','0152');  
      numStr :=  AnsiReplaceStr (numStr,'8482','0153');  
      numStr :=  AnsiReplaceStr (numStr,'0353','0154');  
      numStr :=  AnsiReplaceStr (numStr,'0339','0155');  

      numStr :=  AnsiReplaceStr (numStr,'0382','0158');  
      numStr :=  AnsiReplaceStr (numStr,'0376','0159');
```